# how to upgrade jdbc driver from 10g to 12c in a standalone OC4J

Tags: java, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oc4j, oracle-fusion-middleware

we have an application deployed in standalone oc4j which uses Oracle 10g jdbc driver need  to upgrade this  into 12c jdbc connection

is there any docs for this migration

Comment: Does this mean the application deployed on OC4J 10g, should migrate to Weblogic 12c?

Comment: @jacob, we have one standalone oc4j which uses oracle 10g jdbc driver, recently we migrated our db into oracle 12c and then we are facing some client compatibily issue,

Comment: @jacob, is it possible to migrate the jdbc driver from 10g to 12c

Comment: Download drivers from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html), replace the 10g driver with 12c, restart OC4J instance.